# RIP Stan Lee, Marvel Comics legend

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Marvel Comics legend Stan Lee died at age 95 from causes unknown as of now.

[Stan Lee Dead at 95](https://www.ign.com/articles/2018/11/12/stan-lee-dead-at-95)

The creator of the Fantastic Four, Spider-Man and many more superheroes died today, leaving behind a massive legacy in popular culture and an empire known as Marvel Entertainment.

Comment: Don't forget to mention his military service and philanthropic foundation...

Comment: I mean, he can't really be dead. Someone must've kept a DNA sample to make a clone, or he faked his own death to escape his enemies, or a mystic sorcerer will use forbidden magic, or a cosmic life force will come down from the sky and resurrect him. I say we wait a good 100 issues before stating he's dead. ...Ah, who am I kidding. RIP. :'(

Comment: Do you think they'll give him the *Cushing treatment* and and make him do CGI cameos for eternity?

Comment: Technically dead? Sure. A perfect example of staying alive because you have embedded yourself in the mind of pretty much everyone? Absolutely.

Answer (score 31):

## Excelsior.

Earth has lost one of its mightiest heroes today. I know just about all of us in the SFF community will be saddened by this loss.

If you are ever feeling generous I recommend [The Stan Lee Foundation](http://www.stanleefoundation.org/) because being able to read is superpower that everyone should experience and share with the world.

Answer (score 28):

I mean, I can't say this is totally unexpected - he *was* 95.

But I think the last time the death of someone I've never met hit me this hard was when Jim Henson died, back in the early 1990s.

Goodbye, and thanks for all the incredible stories, and the sense of camaraderie you created between fans and creators with the old "Bullpen Bulletins" page, and "Stan's Soapbox". You'll be missed.

Answer (score 5):

He was the man who was supposed to live forever. Out of nowhere too. I’m so sad, it seemed like he never would die, and then he just did...
My respects to Stan Lee, the greatest guy in the world.